# open an iphone app from a link in a web app in safari

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I am trying to open my native iPhone application from a link in safari. I have followed [this link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) to create a url schema. I have added `appgo://` as my url schema and com.xxxx.appgo as Identifier under URL Types. Following is my link in web page in safari: Open iPhone App
But when I click on the link the app doesn't open up and safari produce an alert with error: Safari cannot enter the page as the address is invalid.

my bundle identifier: com.xxxxx.abc
Note: My bundle identifier is different from the identifier in URL types. Can that be an issue?

**Edit:**
I have made bundle identifier and url identifier same. I have also added following code in my app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
NSLog(@"application");
BOOL returnValue = NO;
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
if([urlString hasPrefix:@"com.xxxx.appgo"]){
    returnValue = YES;
}
return returnValue;
```

}

I am testing it in my iPad. I first install the latest version of app from xcode and then press on home button and then open the link in safari. But I am still getting the alert saying the Safari cannot enter the page as address is invalid. My link in safari:

```
<a href="appgo://">Open iPhone App</a>
```

Comment: paste here the - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url method form app delegate.

Comment: it is empty for now. I havent added anything in this method as of now

Comment: you have to test if your app accepts the url and return yes or no value.

Comment: The scheme-entry in your .plist has to be only "appgo", without "://".

Comment: Thanks a lot Patric... you are my saviour. You got my mistake it works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement in app delegate

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
        BOOL returnValue = NO;
        NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
        if([urlString hasPrefix:@"appgo://"]){  
             returnValue = YES;
        }
       return returnValue;
    }
```

Edit:
Add in your info.plist file

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.xxxx.appgo</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>appgo</string>
                <string>yourSecondScheme</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Please check my edit. I have added your code but still it doesn't open the app.

Comment: I got my problem. I had added :// in the schema. I have removed it and it works fine now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your bundle identifier must be same as the URL types in the plis file.

For more you can refer to [this link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).

Comment: Please check my edit. I have made bundle identifier and url types same but it is still not working for me.

Comment: I don't have a URL-type set in my app, only the scheme, and it works.

Comment: By "plis", do you mean "plist"?